# What information can I get from 'unrecognized selector' log message?

Tags: objective-c

I see this in my log:

> `2011-08-05 17:29:45.994 Test[3834:707] -[MyClass copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102218b90`

what usable information does this line contain to track down exact point where unrecognized selector is sent? My understanding is that `3834` is PID, but I don't know what is `707` value. Also, is unrecognized selector `copyWithZone:` or is that place where the problem occured? (I don't override that method anywhere though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copyWithZone:` is the unrecognized selector. It was being sent to an instance of `MyClass`. My guess is you tried to use this object as a key in an `NSDictionary`? You can only use objects which conform to the `NSCopying` protocol as keys.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This looks like you failed to make `MyClass` a subclass of `NSObject`.</strike> (sorry, @jtbandes is right. It's not `NSObject`, it's `NSCopying`.)

707 is the thread identifier.

To track down where this happened, in the Run menu of Xcode 3, select "Stop on Objective C Exceptions." In Xcode 4, use an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html).

Comment: Are you sure about 707 being thread identifier? I would assume that thread identifier changes in different runs, but this value is constant. I will try that exception breakpoint! Thanks for your answer.